# Right architechture for loose coupling with Ninject, ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ado.net, ninject

I'd appreciate if someone could give an advice on building the right architecture for ASP.NET MVC web app.

I'm currency working on `MVC 5` web application, with `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` which uses **existing database**. The application mainly uses CRUD operations.

I've doubts on the design pattern I'm trying to use in order to reach loose coupling. I'd also like to use `Ninject` dependency injector.

So, my solution includes 3 projects: `Abstractions`, `MVCWebApplication` and `DAL`.
I'd like to get a suggestions on structuring the `Abstractions` project.

Firstly, I've defined the view models for my db entities. I don't use Adapter pattern, instead I'll use `AutoMapper` to map DB and View model classes:

```
namespace MVCWebApplication.Models
{
    public class CustomerVM 
    {
          public int ID {get; set;}
          public string Name {get; set;}
          public Contract Contract {get; set;}
    }
    public class ContractVM
    {
         public string ContractNo {get; set;} //ID
         pulic DateTime AgreementDate {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Generic repository

```
namespace Abstractions
{
    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        T Find(object pk);
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();     
        void Insert(T entity);      
        //...
    }
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {    
        public DbContext context;
        public DbSet<T> dbset;
        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            dbset = context.Set<T>();
        }

        //implementation        
    }
}
```

And UnitOfWork which gives me an access to the repositories:

```
namespace Abstractions
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository { get; } //Customer is DB entity
        IRepository<Contract> ContractRepository { get; } //Contractis DB entity
        //other repositories
        void Save();        
    }


    public partial class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;
        private IRepository<Contract> _contractRepository;
        private CREntities _context;
        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _context = new CREntities();
        }
        public IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository
        {                
            get
            {
                if (_customerRepository == null)
                    _customerRepository = new Repository<Customer>(_context);
                return _customerRepository;
            }
        }
        //other repositories, save & dispose ..

    }
}
```

In `App_Start` I've got:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();                
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
}
```

So, my question is this approach expedient? What is the sense of Ninject here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're building a CRUD application, I would probably just inject the DbContext directly into the controller. Why go with all the abstractions? Or why use MVC anyway? Just build an application with LightSwitch.

Comment: I'd like to use more advanced tools and try to build an architechture for future project extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view on your approach, its nice and there are many people around using it in big applications. So do not worry.

One suggestion, in your above code, you can use IRepository directly instead of using UnitOfWork.XXXRepository. You got generic repository, it will work with any entity (customer, contract, or a new entity)

With having UnitOfWork class the problem is, when you need another repository (for a new entity), you will need to change UnitOfWork class (breaks Open Close Principle).

> What is the sense of Ninject here?

I am not sure if I understand your question fully, Ninject is allowing you to set up your dependencies at one single place and then at runtime injecting these dependencies in your controller or services or wherever used.